# Sort records with field that don't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
| id | article_id | meta_key | meta_value |
|----|------------|----------|------------|
| 1  | 135        | author   | Beth       |
| 2  | 135        | status   | draft      |
| 3  | 135        | paywall  | yes        |
| 4  | 136        | author   | Kim        |
| 5  | 136        | status   | publish    |
| 6  | 137        | author   | Mary       |
| 7  | 137        | status   | publish    |
```

I have to implement a feature which adds the `meta_key` "paywall" with either a **yes** or a **no** `meta_value` to new articles, which means the meta_key "paywall" does not exist for the older records.

I need to fetch the records by meta_key="paywall" and sort by meta_value.
The problem is for the articles without the meta_key "paywall", when the sorting is DESC, the articles are ordered by [ Yes ], [ No ], [ articles without paywall meta key ].

Is there a way in SQL where I can sort by assuming the value of meta_value to be **yes** for a key that does not exist so that the DESC is returned as [ Yes ], [ articles without paywall meta key ], [ No ]?

The query I have:

```
SELECT article_id, meta_key, meta_value
FROM wp_meta
WHERE meta_key="paywall"
ORDER BY meta_value
DESC
```

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: @Mureinik added the query

Comment: If you "need to fetch the articles by meta_key = 'paywall' " I.e WHERE meta_key = 'paywall',  why do you care about the old articles without this meta_key? They aren't part of your result set!

Comment: we need to assume the old articles have paywall with the value as "yes"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
select article_id
from t
group by article_id
order by sum(meta_key = 'paywall' and value = 'yes') desc,
         sum(meta_key = 'paywall') = 0 desc;
```

This puts the "yes"es first.  Then the missing values.  And then the remaining ones (which are presumably "no"s).

Answer (score 0):

One dirty trick you could use is to group by the article ID, and use the `max` operator to get the meta value from a `case` expression that takes the value for `paywall`, and hardcodes a `no` for any other key in order to simulate getting a `no` for articles that don't have this entry:

```sql
SELECT   article_id, 
         'paywall' AS meta_key,
         MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'paywall' THEN meta_value ELSE 'no' END) AS meta_value
FROM     wp_meta
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

> we need to assume the old articles have paywall with the value as "yes"

Just insert "yes" for all the old articles as a one time operation:

```
INSERT INTO wp_meta (article_id, meta_key, meta_value)

SELECT all_ids.article_id, 'paywall', 'yes'
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT article_id FROM wp_meta) all_ids
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT article_id FROM wp_meta WHERE meta_key = 'paywall') paywall_ids
  ON all_ids.article_id = paywall_ids.article_id
WHERE paywall_ids.article_id IS NULL
```

You can run the select without the insert to check that this will work as expected. How it works:

- get a list of all the article ids
- get a list of only articles that already have a paywall
- left join the paywall to all, meaning any article ids in all_ids that don't have a matching is in paywall_ids will produce a NULL in the paywall_ids.article_id column
- check for this null
- create a row to be inserted that specifies the paywall as yes

An alternative way, only to be used if you're certain that article_ids are incrementing and all the article ids without a paywall entry are occurring before a particular id  :

```
INSERT INTO wp_meta (article_id, meta_key, meta_value)

SELECT DISTINCT article_id, 'paywall', 'yes'
FROM
  wp_meta
WHERE 
  article_id < (SELECT MIN(article_id) FROM wp_meta WHERE meta_key = 'paywall')
```

- find the first ID where paywall was used
- select all the unique article ids before that one and create a paywall entry
- insert them

The left join route is safer as it will find any articles that don't have paywall not just all those before a certain id. I only suggest this because you indicate that you turned it on at some point so it's likely that all those before don't have it and all those after do have it

Fixing up your data will always be preferable to running SQLs that hack fake data in- it means you can turn some older articles paywall-no if you want

---

By the way, if you're not finished the paywall feature yet, the simplest way is to insert a paywall record for all articles before you put the feature live! Those other scripts are for if it's already gone live and some records don't have a paywall. If you give all records a value as part of go live the problem of "some have,some don't" never occurs

```
INSERT INTO wp_meta (article_id, meta_key, meta_value)

SELECT DISTINCT article_id, 'paywall', 'yes'
FRON wp_meta
```

Do this as part of your go live script